# Can you wish to Allah for different features on your face?

Tags: halal-haram, human-body

If you ask Allah for a different facial feature would it be allowed? It’s haram to change your face (I think). But what if you asked Allah to change your face,would it still be haram? (I’m only a child I’m not sure that’s why I’m asking)

Answer (score 1):

Salam Alai Kum,

I understand you are a child as you mentioned that :) .

To simplify life. Every stage of your life, the priority in life changes. I tried to explain the 7 stages of life.

The 7 stages:

1. 5 - 12 yrs: you are a child all you care about is having fun and enjoyment and things along those lines
2. 13 - 21 yrs: You are a teen and all you care about is how good and cool you appear and look etc.
3. 22 - 30 yrs: If you are a guy you care about your career if you are a girl maybe marriage, your life after marriage or something like that.
4. 31 - 40 yrs: Stability in life etc. 41 - 50 yrs: Retirement planning, worrying
   about kids future etc.
5. 51 - 60 yrs: Retirement investments, settling kids, getting them married etc.
6. 61 - 70: some of the above and worrying about afterlife
7. 70 - end of life: worrying about after life, trying to do good deeds, Quran tilawat, Salah 5 times a day etc. (basically doing everything possible to get into Jannah)

Every stage of life people make a wish to Allah on things they care about during that stage of life.

At every stage of life when a person looks back at what he wished for during the previous stages of life he laughs and finds the things he cared about were so foolish etc.

I am assuming you are in the 2nd stage of the 7 stages and I am sure you would find the things you wished for and cared about in your 1st stage were foolish. In the same way as you mature your priorities change. So try not to be very obsessed with things you care and worry about now because I guarantee you that in few years your priorities too would change.

So coming back to wishing things to Allah. Feel free to wish Allah anything you desire he understands every person and loves all. He is your best friend to talk to in prayers and duas. Have a conversation with him in your prayers and wishes. Dont shy away from speaking to Allah. But how would you know what not to wish for? The answer is dont wish for things that are clearly known as Sin.

Dont become so obsessed with your facial appearance so that you would want to have a surgery. Believe me that your dressing sense effects your whole appearance. Improve you dressing sense, by dressing sense I mean the colours you choose, the shape of the garment you wear. Do not try to wearing revealing clothes it is a sin. Even if you are covering your whole body but since it is tight it reveals every shape of your body and is a Sin. So work on non-revealing shapes of garments and colours and your hair and a slight makeup :) That should help you look good.